# Is it possible to move in-page style sheet to <head> section using regex replacement?

Tags: javascript, php, css, regex

Supposed I have a html page like this:

Before:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.domain.com/css1.css">
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
.test1{clear:both}
.test2{width:110px}
...
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

After:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.domain.com/css1.css">
<style type="text/css">
.test1{clear:both}
.test2{width:110px}
...
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Just curious if it could be done via Regex replacement?

Thanks a lot.

PS: Or did anybody know how google pagespeed apache2 extension does move the css to head?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a little application that parses through the html file, filters the style tags out, deletes them from the tags and creates a style tag in the head and saves the html file again.

But lets face it, when we are talking here about one or two html files, then you will spend much more time on developing that app than just clean up your mess by hand.

Comment: actually i am on opposite situation as you stated. i need to clean up the designers' mess since 2005. so it gotta be automatically way from now on.

Comment: then it would be a legit possibility to develop such a parser.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on same task in my one project, I have made a javascript regex which selects all inline styles, you can use this in your project.

```
/<(style)[^>]*?>(?:.|\n)*?</\s*\1\s*>/igm
```

You can test this regex at: http://www.regexr.com